# solve html and css rectangle button design?

Tags: html, css, web

how to design in html and css code? it is properly design this problem solve

[image]

I try this problem but i cannot do it. i want to this problem solve with html and css code.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.trapezium-button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  /* Background color of the rectangle */
  color: #fff;
  /* Text color */
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #2980b9;
  /* Border color */
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.trapezium-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 120% 100%);
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  /* Background color of the trapezium */
  z-index: 0;
}

.diagonal-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 120% 100%);
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}

.trapezium-button span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezium-button">
  <span>Button Text</span>
  <div class="trapezium-background"></div>
  <div class="diagonal-line"></div>
</div>
```

You may adust the shape by adjusting the values in line `clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 120% 100%);` under `.trapezium-background`and `.diagonal-line`, especially what you see as `120%`.

Hope this is what you were looking for and you are able to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the design an approach to the solution could be based on the CSS perspectives and rotations.

```css
.container{
    height: 76px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 550px;
}

.button {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 38deg ) rotateZ( 1deg );
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 220px;
    background: #3bd770;
}

.container span {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button"></div>
  <span>Join us today!</span>
</div>
```